# Which of these are getting called?

Tags: c++

Say I have the following code:

```
struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

class mydateclass {
    public: 
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
};

mydateclass date;

date.day;
```

Which `date` variable is being referred to? The `date` instance named `mydateclass`, or the `date` struct?

Comment: Why do you have a `mydateclass` if it has the exact same data members as the `date` class? Why don't you have a semicolon at the end of `mydateclass`? Why don't you compile the code and see what happens?

Comment: Could you please be a little more clear. What do you mean by which one to call. Are you trying to understand which class to use or what is the difference between the struct and the class. From what you have provided, the date.day will indeed call your class.

Comment: What are you guys talking about? Not only is this a good question, I don't even see the part you're getting confused on. I tried editing it to make it blatantly clear, but there was nothing wrong with the original question

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: I think I understood what the OP is asking; still, a question that just reports a code snippet, and that is titled "Ambiguity? Which to call?" is not the best of clear questions. The answer to "which to call?" is not what the OP wants to hear.

Comment: @kia Sure, the title was wrong, but it was a minor language barrier issue and a minor technical mistake; he said "Which to call" instead of "Which is called", where "called" is referring to variable referencing

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: I think it would be faster to write test code to verify what the code does, then to ask here. It could be the OP is using a computer without compiler, right now, but to check what he asked doesn't require to compile an application of 3500 code lines.

Comment: @kia Also true, but if people want to take the time to ask a question here they're more than welcome to, and that's not a reason to close the question. It might take longer for this particular person to get the answer, but in theory the next 100 people that have this problem will Google it and find the answer here in a couple seconds

Comment: Anyway, I voted to re-open the question. I think that is clearer, now, what the OP means.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: That is true too. I generally don't judge why somebody asks a question here; I simply reported what I believe others thought. I personally think that replies like "check yourself", "search on Google" could be used to almost all the questions asked here; in that case, what is the purpose of this site?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: "I think it would be faster to write test code to verify what the code does" -- be careful! It may be undefined behavior and then your program breaks with another compiler. VC++ eats a lot of stuff that GCC wouldn't even touch.

Comment: @ypnos: That is a good point too. I should remember that when somebody says that for a question I ask. I personally don't find the "try it yourself" a good answer, as I already said, not even when reported in a comment; you made a point about why the question could be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct *declaration* is called "date". There is no object *date* created before `mydateclass date;`. Therefore, the "call" is not ambigeous.

If you want to create an object in that fashion it would be:

```
struct datestruct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} date;
```

If you would do that, your compiler should complain at `mydateclass date;`, as an object of that name already exists.

Note that if you want to deal with the member (e.g. static member) of a class/struct w/o having an object at hands, you need :: instead of . Such as:

```
struct date {
    static int day;
};

date::day;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no ambiguity.
The code defines a structure, but it doesn't create an instance of it. When you write `date.day`, you are referring to a variable, and there is just a variable named `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `date` in this code is declared to be an instance of `mydateclass`, that's the type whose members you can access through the variable `date`.

A quick test with slightly modified code shows, that a variable hides the struct by the same name:

```
struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

class mydateclass {
    public:
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
};

int main()
{
    mydateclass date;

    date.day;

    date other_date;  //error here, because "date" does not name a type in this context
    ::date yet_another_date; //okey, because "::" means the name in question is in global scope
                             //whereas the variable named "date" is local to main
}

void foo()
{
    date other_date;  //ok here, because there is no variable called "date" in scope here
}
```

Whether you have a struct or a class, makes no difference to the question.